# Deaton's AIDS/QAIDS model

Tags: development-economics

Im new to economics and want to understand the AIDS/QAIDs model of Angus Deaton. Can anyone suggest possible readings for the same as a background knowledge??

Comment: I am not sure if you want to understand the AIDS model or everything needed to understand the AIDS model in general, including microeconomics, econometrics and math (additions, functions, differentials). Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, [the original article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1805222). [Banks et. al](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2951405) (1997) discuss its assumptions. This [survey](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2233510) might also be helpful.